# plus() and minus method

Tags: java

Ok so I am going to try this again.  I have a very basic calculator application.  I am currently having trouble figuring out how to get my plus() and minus() methods to work.  Whenever I run the code, the plus() method is adding currentValue + currentValue.  I want it to act like a calculator and add two different integers together.  Any suggestions?

```
digitButton(buttons, 0);
JButton plus = new JButton("+");
plus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    myAccumulator.plus();
    updateDisplay();
  }
});
buttons.add(plus);
return buttons;
```

this is where it is getting called.

And this is my class that I wrote with my plus () method.

```
public class BasicAccumulator implements Accumulator {

    private int digit;
    private int currentValue;

    public void BasicAccumulator(int digit, int currentValue)
    {
        this.digit = digit;
        this.currentValue = currentValue;
    }

    public void addDigit(int digit)
    {
        currentValue = currentValue * 10 + digit;
    }

    public void plus()
    {
        if (currentValue != 0)
            digit = currentValue;
            currentValue = currentValue + digit;

    }

    public void minus()
    {
        currentValue = currentValue - digit;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        currentValue = 0;
    }

    public int displayValue()
    {
        return currentValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: `plus` is   answer_variable = variable1 + variable2;       `minus` is answer_varable = variable1 - variable2;

Comment: But in my case that does not work.  I have tried that! I do something like currentValue = currentValue + digit;  Yet nothing happens.

Comment: Here's a few tips for improving your question (and stop it getting downvoted!):
  (1) Please state your question very clearly. "I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do" doesn't help me (and others, no doubt) understand exactly what you're trying to figure out and where you're stuck.


(2) Whether it is or not, this looks very much like a homework question. If it is (or even if it isn't), please take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions for tips on improving your question. :) Good luck

Comment: maybe nothing happens because `currentValue` or `digit` are 0 so no addition happens. You should do some debugging.. get a IDE thats capable of debugging (pausing code) and running it line by line.

Comment: For better help soon, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) version of your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about it.  At the time you press +, you presumably have not yet entered the second number.  That is, if your calculator is intended to work like most calculators out there...

Presumably you have the following sequence of events..

1. Type in digits: digits go in the current accumulator to create a number
2. Press +: digits are stored away
3. Type in digits, digits are accumulated as in 1
4. Press =: current accumulated number is added to previous one.

For this, I would conceptually store 3 things in the accumulator:

- The 'left' value (left-hand side of the equation) - ie the number that was stored after + was pressed
- The current operation - nothing initially, but will be set to a value that indicates whether + or -.
- The current accumulated value (i'll just call it 'right')

So...  Initially, `left` is zero and `operation` is nothing (ie 'clear').

```
State: left(0), operation(empty), right(0)
```

Type in some digits...  These are built up in 'right'.

```
State: left(0), operation(empty), right(22)
```

Press +.  Now, you apply any pending operation to `left`.  In this case the operation is empty, so you just copy the value and clear 'right'.  Then you set the operation to '+'

```
State: left(22), operation(+), right(0)
```

You type in more digits, once again building up `right`.

```
State: left(22), operation(+), right(20)
```

You hit + again.  Now the operation is applied.  You add `right` to `left` and clear `right`.

```
State: left(42), operation(+), right(0)
```

*etc etc*...

Comment: That is explained very well thank you! But I am still a little confused.  How can I store those values in left and right without creating another variable or using a data structure?

Comment: Well, in your case `digit` is equivalent to my `right` and `currentValue` is equivalent to my `left`.  You just need to add a variable to your class that represents the operation.  Use an `enum` type for this.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `digit` in two locations: as a member and as an argument to `addDigit`. The former doesn't appear to make a lot of sense to me.

Most basic operations like `plus` require *two numbers* to work on. You'll either have to provide one of them to the function call, or store both of them in your class. You could use the existing `digit` member for the latter, but unless you only want to add single digits, I'd advise against that name.

Instead, consider what your sequence of operations is. Do you enter *two* numbers and then press the operation button? If so, you'll need to store two numbers, e.g. `value` and `current`. Digits would be appended to `current` and any operation like `plus` would add `current` to `value` before resetting `current` to zero. The display should probably reflect `value` after each operation, but `current` after each digit, so you'll need some boolean flag to distinguish these two situations.

If you enter one number, then press the operation button, and then enter another number (infix operators), most of the above suggestions still apply, but in addition you'll need some way to store the operation while reading the second number. You could do so using some character, string, number, or enum constants. I'd personally do this using enum constants which already contain the instructions to compute that operation, but that's pretty advanced syntax. Each operation button press would evaluate the previously stored operation and then store a new operation, except perhaps for "=".

Answer (score 1):

This *at least* looks like it's a source of confusion:

```
public void plus()
{
    if (currentValue != 0)
        digit = currentValue;
        currentValue = currentValue + digit;

}
```

When you add bracing in and fix the indentation, that code is actually:

```
public void plus()
{
    if (currentValue != 0)
    {
        digit = currentValue;
    }
    currentValue = currentValue + digit;
}
```

Is that actually what you intended? It seems unlikely. If you were expecting indentation to affect behaviour, you should rewrite the code as:

```
public void plus()
{
    if (currentValue != 0)
    {
        digit = currentValue;
        currentValue = currentValue + digit;
    }
}
```

It's also not clear *why* you'd want this behaviour in the first place. As requested on your previous question, it would really help if you'd write a short but complete *console* application exercising your class, along with a statement of the *expected* behaviour vs the *actual* behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing something like this.

```
int plus(int first, int second)
{
   return first + second;
}
```

this is the problem right here:

```
digit = currentValue;
currentValue = currentValue + digit;
```

you set the digit equal to currentValue so it becomes

```
currentValue = currentValue + currentValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `plus()` you're doing

```
digit = currentValue;
currentValue = currentValue + digit;
```

which to me looks like

```
currentValue = currentValue + currentValue
```

You should use

```
currentValue = currentValue + digit;
```

only